# Iphone image from UIImagePicker doesn't show

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

i have a TabBarController in which one tab has an ImageView. Besides, i have a button to display the ImagePicker and the following code:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
                             didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    imageView.image = image;
}
```

But the image doesn't show in the ImageView when this method is called.

Any idea?

Thanks

(I have tried in a separately view and it works so i don't know what is happening)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are dismissing your picker first thing, you can try:

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
imageView.image = image;
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

or you can try this delegate:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
       didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image 
                 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {

    NSData *chosenImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

    yourImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:chosenImage];

}
```

Comment: Are you using the <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> in your header?